# Can we have one single app with two different projects in two different programming languages?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I've an app on App store. The old source code is in `objective-c`, but now I am coding the app in `Swift` language. I've made a new project. I want to know whether the app store will accept my new source code which is in Swift? If Yes, then what's the procedure. I mean how can I upload the new source code to the app store. Isn't there any issue with bundle identifier or so?

> Basically I want to know that can we have one single app with two
>   different projects in two different programming languages?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: App in App Store identified solely by bundle id (app version version should be increased) So you can develop completely different app, but deploy it with same BundleId - and it will replace your original app.

Comment: thanks @MichaelVorontsov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can target two different projects to the same app in iTunes Connect. You just need to set the same bundle identifier in the project. Make sure that you count up the version number or build number like you do for your usual releases.

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to integrate the Objtive-C Code with a bridge to the Swift one,

other then that if you create a new app simply give it the same bundle Identifier with a new build/Version